# 'timeout expired' error with PDO connection to Redshift

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, pdo

I'm getting the following error when trying to connect to a Redshift cluster using PDO.

*SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired*

It was working two days ago without any issues.  I deleted the cluster while I wasn't using it and restored it from the backup this morning to continue working on it.  I can connect to it via SQLWorkbench J and perform queries, it seems to just be the PDO connection which is a problem.

All indicators on the cluster are green and healthy, I've checked the security settings and ensured the correct role is applied to the cluster. Nothing has altered in the database or my code.  I'm completely stumped as to why it's no longer working!

-- edit --

I can connect to a different cluster without issue - can redshift clusters corrupt?!

Comment: Has anything in the connection changed i.e. ip address etc

Comment: @RiggsFolly I did wonder that, but the connection Endpoint is the same as it was previously

Comment: I found a thread on aws.amazon where they had this problem and the last thing in the thread is the OP saying `After I added EC2 instance to the security group, it is working correctly.` - don't know if that means anything to you as I'm not familiar with redshift/ec2

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I restored the cluster from a backup and used a different name (simply appended '-dev' to the end of the name) and it's working again. I made no other changes - very strange.